How to link a pull request to existing project item?
In GitHub Project (new), we can add new item that link to a pr/issue or convert a draft item to issue. However, is there any way to link an existing pr/issue to an existing project item?
I can only find the way to add new item or new issue.
I can only add a link in the item's content, but that's not what I want. I want the link to appear in title.
